# Windows 7 RTM vhd

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can i dual boot XP and Windows 7 RTM vhd file in Windows XP without using any Windows 7 DVD?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as Boot from VHD is a feature in the Windows 7 Boot Loader.... Also, there are many restrictions and whilst "it works" it is annoying to use a VHD as a normal OS.

Instead, what I recommend you do is download and install [Microsoft Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) then you can use Windows 7 virtually from within your Windows XP session.

Comment: VPC or do a real dual boot.